# How to show in aspx page (WebForms) the wait process while some method is executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, triggers, webforms

How can I show some type of message in my ASPX web page ( *I'm using WebForms, not MVC* ), which represents as a "wait process" while some method of my project is executing.

I'm not asking about how to make some HTML/CSS/DOM stuff, I'm asking more about asynchronous check.

**For e.g.:** some data from web could be delivered to client not quickly and when it does occur - it looks very ugly for the user. It's just idling and looks like a page with bug, where there is no well highlighted status ( *many users don't watch in browsers the page loading states, they want to look it in web applications exactly, like in desktop applications* ).

I want to show a message like ***"waiting for the operation end"***
and I don't know how to make an asynchronous check in my ASPX page for getting the current state when some methods execute ( *are they finished or not etc...* ).

What I really want looks like in pseudo-code:

```
while (methodExecuting) show(waitMessage);
```

How could it be done in WebForms of ASP.NET project?

Comment: how long does the method takes to run? seconds? minutes?

Comment: @NewPin 5-10 seconds, differently and not stable time, because of large data load/checks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use a "**progressBar**" indicating your condition periodically.
Here is a good link explaining step by step how to use it.

[Asynchronous processing in ASP.Net with Ajax **progress** bar](http://weblogs.asp.net/seanmcalinden/archive/2009/11/15/asynchronous-processing-in-asp-net-mvc-with-ajax-progress-bar.aspx)

You can download this solution at the following: http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/seanmcalinden/Solutions/AjaxProgressBarExample.zip

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it with JQuery UI Progress Bar.

Change your C# function to webmethod and then call it with jquery. here is the [tutorial](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#label) for you. Call the webmethod and enable the progress bar, when it is completed disable the progress bar.

hope it helps.

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery, because it conflicts with the Microsoft AJAX. I know , that jQuery allows to rename the symbol $ to any one (and so it wouldn't be any conflicts), but I'm controlling all stuff  in my project with the WebForms and purely it would be rather strange (as for me) to use 2 techniques, which allow to use the similar stuff, but in different ways. I think, jQuery is more suitable for ASP.NET MVC, not ASP.NET WebForms.