# c# - asynchronous code that updates method progress to page

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, webforms

I have read up a bit on writing asynchronous code, but I still have a lot of questions specifically regarding to my programming task. In my web forms application, on a button click, I want to run a method in another class that performs a task (inserting data into db) while updating the screen on its progress. For example:

```
btn1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call methodA asynchronously? 
}
```

methodA is contained in another class and queries database:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public void methodA(param)
    {
        //insert data into database
        //create string that notifies the progress of the method (should be displayed on page)

        //insert more data into database
        //alter string to re-notify of the progress of the method (to be displayed on page)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to fill a string which would be displayed to the page in the form of a label as the method progresses. I don't know if methodA would be return type "void" but I put it there anyway. I figure this task should be completed asynchonously or maybe with the use of a web service. So how would I do this programmatically?

**EDIT**

I have read many articles, but none seem to describe the process in my situation effectively. They all just describe either displaying a message at the beginning or end when a long running job does its work (in this case methodA). I want the method to spit out a string (describing where it is at in the method i.e. "inserted first set of data" ...) and display it to the page multiple times as it progresses. Is this sort of thing too ambitious in my case with webforms... What if I were to call a web service that does all the work and brings back messages?

Comment: There are plenty of questions on "how to show progress of long running operation on web page"... Consider searching yourself as it does not look like anyone knows good duplicate.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Please read my first edit.

Comment: I don't know.... Myaby you should show link to the best of "many" articles...  Top links I get for http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20how%20to%20show%20progress%20of%20long%20running%20operation%20on%20web%20page most say "start operation, each step should update progress in some persistent state and than poll for that progress via client script on timer". You can add "long poll", "websocket", or "singnalR" to search request for solutions with more immediate feedback.

Comment: Couple links - basic polling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849236/update-a-web-page-as-a-process-runs , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737766/how-to-show-in-aspx-page-webforms-the-wait-process-while-some-method-is-execut, SignalR - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852586.aspx

Answer (score 2):

From your description is seems like you want to use the async/await pattern? That would be appropriate here. Without knowing more specifics about what your `methodA` does, it's impossible to give you an exact implementation. But here's an example of what it might look like:

```
async void btn1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call methodA asynchronously
    await MethodA(2);
}

public async Task MethodA(int param)
{
    await Task.Run(() => InsertDataIntoDatabase());
    statusTextBox.Text = "first insert done";
    await Task.Run(() => InsertMoreDataIntoDatabase());
    statusTextBox.Text = "second insert done";
}
```

The above assumes that your database-insertion methods aren't already async methods. If they are, then they don't need to be wrapped in a Task. If you have multiple statements in your method to accomplish this, then for readability it would be best to encapsulate those statements in a separate method. Maybe you'd even reuse the code for the first and second insert.

Note also that you can do all the normal things, like looping. So if you have multiple database inserts but it can be written as a loop, it's fine to do that:

```
public async Task MethodA(int param)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < param; i++)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => InsertDataIntoDatabase(i));
        statusTextBox.Text = "insert #" + i + " done";
    }
}
```

That should get you started. There are numerous existing questions on SO regarding this general technique, and of course MSDN has documentation and tutorials for it. If you have more questions, you should start there.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I am looking for to get me headed in the right direction. One more question though. I have methodA in a separate class so do I need to pass the string somehow so the aspx.cs page can fill the label with that string?

Comment: +0 Note that while correct (and directly applicable to *WinForms*) this answer really does not help much with any web cases (WebForms/Web services/ASP.Net MVC) as asked in the question.

Comment: @RyanGray: I don't know how your different components are organized. Assuming the class containing `methodA` does not already have view-related logic, I would not add any. But I would expect it would make sense to expose an event on that class for such notification purposes...then your page code would subscribe to that event, and in that way allow the other class to pass the notification strings to it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: thanks for the feedback. You're right that I did not take any particular care to frame the answer specifically for the web scenario. I'm not even all that familiar with web forms and its ilk. However, while there may not be the same thread-affinity issues as exist in regular WinForms programs, I assume that the async/await pattern is still useful in terms of semantically representing these kinds of operations and my answer was offered in that spirit. I encourage you to offer a different answer which is more directly useful to Ryan; I would happily up-vote such a post.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - there are already "couple" answers dealing with "show progress during long operations in ASP.Net"... The main difference Web/WinForms is inability to give feedback from middle of the operation. You are starting at browser - think about all that code that run on server to construct that page and whole operation have one single result - page you see. WebForms is actually make thing worse to understand the issue as it looks like you have controls you can change (similar to WinForms) but such change does not show up till request complete and send to user.